# How to make if condition to continue if the object value is not there..?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am checking the value in object, once the value is not there, just i want to continue the rest of the functions..

how to do this..?

here is my sample:

```
var obj = {"name":""}

if(!obj.name){
    "continue further" //how to make it to continue apart from else part?
}else{
    console.log("name is there");
}

//go for stuff to work always. name is not an issue;
```

Comment: I quiet do not get the question but I would say: simple return; ?

Comment: return true might be?

Comment: what do you mean with *apart from else part?* you want then that the code at *go for stuff to work always* will be executed?

Comment: I have further function, that should not be stoped. when i am not getting (!.obj.name) - true.

Comment: voted to close as the entire question is premised off a misconception.

Answer (score 2):

Your entire question is based on a misconception.

You *appear* to be asking how to make your `if ()` clause do *nothing* except fall through to beyond the `else` clause if the `obj.name` field is falsey.  Well, that's trivial - just put *no code* in the `if` block:

```
var obj = { name: '' }
if (!obj.name) {
    // this block does nothing
} else {
    console.log('name is there');
}

// continue here regardless
```

However your rationale for doing so is bogus - it is *not* best practise to always test the logical negation (i.e. `!obj.name`).  Wherever you learnt that from, it's wrong!  It would be completely acceptable, clearer, and *semantically identical* to test for `obj.name` and turn your current `else` block into an `if` block:

```
if (obj.name) { // name has a value
    console.log('name is there');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var obj = {"name":""};
if (obj.name) {
    console.log("name is there");
    return false;    //Or return true even
}
//go for stuff to work always. name is not an issue;
```

And you can check the name on `trim` also(may be for is null..??) and if you want to continue the process even then can remove return statement

Comment: no i like to use the "!obj.name" - since this is faster.

Comment: faster in the sence..??

Comment: i came to know, this is better practice compare to checking the vlaues

Comment: @3gwebtrain you came to know wrong.  It's perfectly acceptable (and no worse in performance) to say `if (obj.name)`

Comment: Yes you are right @Alnitak..it can be the acceptable performance like !obj.name

Comment: performance is the same, because it checks if its there. If you add the ***!*** it just negates the result...

Comment: BTW, your `return` is not required - the OP appears to want to just skip the `else` clause (which of course happens anyway) if the name is not defined.  And it's only convoluted like that because he mistakenly believes that it's wrong to write `if (obj.name)`

Comment: ofcourse @Alnitak but I thought may he wants to stop the flow also..

Comment: @3gwebtrain `!obj.name` will return `true` even if `obj.name` is equal to `0`

Comment: Who has downvoted this..??tell me the reason

Comment: no, he said "stuff to work always. name is not an issue" - i.e. keep on processing.  (not my downvote, BTW)

Comment: Ok I have mentioned in my ans...thanku